# Update config value of windows service without restart

Tags: c#, config

My windows service is not reading updated valued from config file.

Let's i have a sample file of abc.exe.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MySolution.Shared.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Dummy" value="dummyValue"/>
  </appSettings>
  <applicationSettings>
     <MySolution.Shared.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="SiteFilter_Allowed" serializeAs="String">
        <value>HIT124</value>
      </setting>
    </MySolution.Shared.Properties.Settings>
   </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now i have to update value of **SiteFilter_Allowed** property.
Manually i updated value of SiteFilter_Allowed to HIT123 in abc.exe.config.
In application, before reading above property i wrote:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(@"applicationSettings\MySolution.Shared.Properties.Settings");
```

But updated value is not reflected i.e. application still using cached value.

I tried for appSetting it worked fine.

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings);
```

I also tried like

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("MySolution.Shared.Properties.Settings");
```

I also tried :

```
 var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(@"applicationSettings\MySolution.Shared.Properties.Settings");
```

I also tried:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("applicationSettings);
```

None of above combination worked.

Comment: Is it possible that you have defined the setting as a User setting instead of an application setting?

Comment: NO, I have defined settings as application setting. @IgnacioSolerGarcia